# Eclipse giving error at @SequenceGenerator "schema" not a valid attribute

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

```
@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(schema = "cobra_oltp",name = "INTERFACE_ACTIVITY_LOG_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_INTERFACE_ACTVTY_LOG", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "INTERFACE_ACTIVITY_LOG_GENERATOR")
```

The abbove codein eclipse showing that "The attribute schema is undefined for the annotation type SequenceGenerator". Can you please help me out as far as I know its a valid attribute. I am using JPA for implementation.

Comment: Which JPA realization/vendor do you use ? (EclipseLink ? Hibernate ?)

Answer (score 0):

Check your versions. As you can see in [documentation for Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html), `schema` attribute doesn't exist. But, in [documentation for Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) it is there. It's just the matter of what you use / what you need.